# Scapy: How to manipulate Host in http header?

Tags: python, packet, scapy

I wrote this piece of code to get http header and set Host:

```
http_layer = packet.getlayer(http.HTTPRequest).fields
http_layer['Host'] = "newHostName"
return packet
```

After running the afforementioned code,the new host name has been set correctly, but the problem is that when I write the packet in pcap file, I still see the previous host in http fields,
Is there an absolute way to manipulate `http_layer['Host']` ?
Any help would be appreciated.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, found the answer.
The key is that `scapy` firstly parses `HTTP Request` and shows the dict of its fields. So when we try to assign a new field like `Host`, it changes the `Host` which it has already parsed and does not change the original field value.
So, this is the way to modify `Host` or any other respective fields:

```
str_headers = pkt['HTTP']['HTTP Request'].fields['Headers']
str_headers = str_headers.replace('Host: ' + pkt['HTTP']['HTTP Request'].fields['Host'], 'Host: ' + new_val)
pkt['HTTP']['HTTP Request'].fields['Headers'] = str_headers
return pkt
```