# Modify HTTP headers and URL path with Python Scapy

Tags: python, scapy, netfilter

I'm running Debian, Python 2.7 and Scapy/netfilterqueue.

This code works and seems to change the destination and port for a given package:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7
from scapy.all import *
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue

def modify(packet):
    pkt = IP(packet.get_payload())

    if pkt.haslayer(TCP) and pkt.getlayer(TCP).dport == 5678:

        pkt.dst = 'my-secure-domain.com'
        pkt.dport = 443

        del pkt[IP].chksum
        del pkt[TCP].chksum
        packet.set_payload(str(pkt))
    packet.accept()

nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(1, modify)
try:
    print "[*] waiting for data"
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

I would like to be able to change and/or add HTTP headers, and the URL path, such as `auth('user':'pass')` HTTP header and `/my-folder/` in the URL path.

But I seem unable to found out how, I have Googled around... :(

Comment: I've also tried to check for `pkt['HTTP']` and `pkt.haslayer(Raw)` but both turns out false.

Comment: this link may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763486/scapy-how-to-manipulate-host-in-http-header